# How do I include error bars on multple line plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot the error bars using  on the multiple line plots with the data in this code. I have encountered many bugs which makes it impossible for the code to run e.g the turple is out of range.

```py
    from numpy import *
    import math
    import seaborn as sns
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import  matplotlib.colors as mcolors
    from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
    from matplotlib.ticker import(MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter, AutoMinorLocator)

    t = np.array([0.5,1, 2, 5, 10, 19]) 
    raw_1 =np.array([0.82, 0.84, 0.86, 0.88, 0.89, 0.895] )
    raw_2 = np.array([0.79, 0.83, 0.84, 0.845, 0.85, 0.865])
    raw_3 = np.array([0.80, 0.81,0.83,0.845, 0.853, 0.80])   
  
    plt.xticks(t, t)

    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=150)
    plt.xlabel("Temporal Context length(s) seconds")
    plt.ylim(0.76, 0.90)
    plt.xlim(0.5, 19)
    plt.ylabel("Balanced Accuracy")

    plt.xticks(t, t)

    plt.xticks(t) 
    plt.errorbar(t, raw_1,yerr=np.std(raw_1, axis = 1),color='r',marker='o')                    
    plt.errorbar(t, raw_2 , yerr= np.std(raw_2, axis = 1)color='g', marker='x')  
    plt.errorbar(t, raw_3 , yerr= np.std(raw_3, axis = 1),color='b')
    plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
    plt.xticks(t,t)
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig('context_bb.png',bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: The way you want to plot it right now is a bit confusing for me: You want to plot data which consists of unique points. And then you want to add errorbars to them, which show the standard deviation across the whole dataset? This seems misleading to me. I would plot the mean of all three raw datasets and use the standarddeviation between the three datasets instead.

Comment: @Christian Karcher, thanks for your thoughts on this approach. Can you implement your approach from my data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, I would advice to calculate the mean and standard deviation of the data and use this result in the errorbar

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.array([0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 19])
raw_1 = np.array([0.82, 0.84, 0.86, 0.88, 0.89, 0.895])
raw_2 = np.array([0.79, 0.83, 0.84, 0.845, 0.85, 0.865])
raw_3 = np.array([0.80, 0.81, 0.83, 0.845, 0.853, 0.80])

# combine data into single matrix
data = np.stack((raw_1, raw_2, raw_3))
# calculate mean and standard deviation
data_mean = data.mean(axis=0)
data_std = data.std(axis=0)

# plot mean with standard deviations as errorbars
plt.errorbar(t, data_mean, yerr=data_std, label='mean and standard deviation')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, with small changes and corrections you could do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.array([0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 19])
raw_1 = np.array([0.82, 0.84, 0.86, 0.88, 0.89, 0.895])
raw_2 = np.array([0.79, 0.83, 0.84, 0.845, 0.85, 0.865])
raw_3 = np.array([0.80, 0.81, 0.83, 0.845, 0.853, 0.80])

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=150)
plt.xlabel("Temporal Context length(s) seconds")
plt.ylim(0.76, 0.90)
plt.xlim(0.5, 19)
plt.ylabel("Balanced Accuracy")

plt.errorbar(t, raw_1, yerr=np.std(raw_1, axis=0), color='r', marker='o')
plt.errorbar(t, raw_2, yerr=np.std(raw_2, axis=0), color='g', marker='x')
plt.errorbar(t, raw_3, yerr=np.std(raw_3, axis=0), color='b')
plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
plt.xticks(t, t)
plt.savefig('context_bb.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]